# network statistics of each queue in a multiqueue system

Tags: linux, files, kernel, drivers, ethernet

I have an NIC with multiqueue support so that based on priority of packets different queues will be used. I want to analyze the packet flow through each of these hardware queue.

> The queues are listed in
>
> `/sys/class/net/eth1/queues/`
>
> directoryI have checked in the directory 
>   `/sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-0/` but it has information such as
>   tx_maxrate, tx_timeout etc.

Is there any other directory where I can see the statistics of each queue?
(Like number of send packets, lost packets etc)

Answer (score 3):

What you see under `/sys/class/net/*/queues/` are the driver/hardware-dependent limits, but all the decisions are made (and statistics are collected) at the network scheduling layer. This layer is managed through the rtnetlink interface, for example using the `tc` tool.

As you have mentioned priorities and queues, I'm assuming that you already have scheduling set up, perhaps using the `mqprio` scheduler. If not, the [Traffic Control HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/) will get you started. Although it's somewhat outdated, the basics are still the same.

To see the statistics for each scheduling class (mapped to a HW transmission queue), use `tc -s class show dev eth1`.

Comment: I was thinking tc tool was for traffic shaping in software and traffic shaping in hardware as a part of the NIC driver in use.

Comment: The hardware will decide from which queue to transmit the next packet. However, something needs to fill the queues first (decide which packets belong where, what traffic is high-priority …). The common scheduling layer handles this (using special schedulers `mq`/`mqprio`) and thus the same `tc` tool is still used to configure it. (Having different configuration mechanisms for essentially the same task doesn't make much sense). See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/multiqueue.txt) for an introduction.